# How to keep a column of dataframe as dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Question: how to extract a column of dataframe and keep its structure as unchanged?

```
data <- iris
data[, 1] ##this will be a vector and will lose the name of the column in dataframe
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`data[, 1, drop = FALSE]` will do the trick.

Answer (score 9):

Use list subsetting which will return a data frame:

```
data[1]
```

Produces

```
  Sepal.Length
1          5.1
2          4.9
3          4.7
4          4.6
5          5.0
6          5.4
# ... omitted rows
```

When you use only one argument to `[` with data frames it subsets data frames as lists, where each column is an element.  It also preserves attributes, so the subset of the data frame is also a data frame.